invoke a local BASH script function from Unix find command on Solaris os
I need to do below
#!/bin/bash 

processFile() {
    echo $1

}

find . -type f -amin 88 -exec processFile {} \;

is this possible??
thanks for help
B Ravi Shankar

Did you try it? It will show find: ‘processFile’: No such file or directory because the exec will spawn a subshell that does not inherit functions. But I have no idea if there is a way to make it inherit functions.

Note that echo $1 doesn't work in general.  See Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo).  A reliable alternative is printf '%s\n' "$1"

find runs in a child process of your bash, which means that the thing running after -exec is the grand-child process. You have to specify an executable program there. Of course you can do a -exec bash ... and, if you export the function, its definition will be available there, but since it is a different process, the non-exported variables of your calling bash process won't be visible, which you need to take into consideration when designing your function. The question remains: Is it worth the trouble?

Why not just make processFile a separate shell script, rather than a function?

I cannot make it a separate shell script. as it need to access variables

I think the key issue is on the find command that cannot directly use shell function.
find . -type f -amin 88 -exec processFile {} \;

Try to use a while loop to read the results of find line by line.
processFile() {
    echo "$1"
}

find . -type f -amin 88 | while IFS= read -r file; do
    processFile "$file"
done


My problem is read is modifying the times on the file. And also somehow if I enable the -x . The log file where I am redirecting the log is growing into GB I.e. Because so the content of the file is also getting logged into the file

Export bash function and call bash:
#!/bin/bash

processFile() {
    echo "$1"
}
export -f processFile
find . -type f -amin -88 -exec bash -c 'processFile "{}"' -- \;

A better solution that works with " and ' in filenames. The export is not needed here:
while IFS= read -r -d '' par; do 
    processFile "$par"
done < <( find . -type f -amin -88 -print0 ) 


This doesn't work for filenames containing whitespace or shell metacharacters.  It is also vulnerable to code injections (it can run commands embedded in filenames).  See Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' ;).

Added quotes to '{}'. Now metacharacters work and code injection is not longer possible. Tested it with files a b, a;b and a&b.

Create a file by running touch "'a b'" and try it again.  Code injection is still possible too.  See Bash Pitfalls #52 (find . -exec sh -c 'echo {}' ;) for a safe alternative.

Anyway, prefer -exec bash -c 'processFile "$@"' -- ';'

@KamilCuk You also need to account for the argument bash -c uses to set $0. --exec bash -c 'processFile "$1"' _ {} ;

Another solution, that works with " and ': while IFS= read -r -d '' par; do processFile "$par"; done < <( find . -type f -amin -88 -print0 )

Boo, hiss re: the injection vulnerability. This is so very close to a good answer, but letting malicious filenames run arbitrary code is a deal-killer. (Quotes in the filenames aren't necessary for a vulnerability -- consider filenames that contain $(...)). Why even leave the bad code in (much less leave it first and prominent)?

...you can do something that's safe, reliable, and high-performance with -exec bash -c without needing to cut over to the -print0 approach, too -- make it -exec bash -c 'for arg; do processFile "$arg"; done' -- _ {} + and there you are; no more vulnerability, plus you're reusing one copy of bash to run multiple items.

after exporting can I access variables defined in the script file?
